# SQL Server 2008 bulk import issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive been working with this for a while and can't find out what I'm doing wrong. I have a CSV file with data such as

```
123,Jon,Son,M,1
```

When I run the query

```
BULK INSERT MYDB2..Dependent FROM 'c:\db3\db.csv'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '/n')
```

I get errors like

> *Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 5 (AGE).*

The thing is I made EXACT copies of the tables so there is no way my tables can't match.

I believe the problem is my the format of my query.

Answer (score 1):

It does have a little problem, it should be \n, instead of /n

```
BULK INSERT [Dependent] FROM 'c:\db3\db.csv'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR=',' ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```